# Big or small characters on registration

Tags: php, html, css, database

I need add function, if someone enter username with big characters, it will be saved with small characters to db.

```
if(empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true){
   $register_data = array(
    'username' => $_POST['username'],
    'first_name' => $_POST['first_name'],
    'last_name' => $_POST['last_name'],
    'email' => $_POST['email'],
    'password' => $_POST['password'],
    'joined' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'email_code' => md5($_POST['username'] + microtime()),
);
```

Comment: http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.strtolower.php

Answer (score 1):

[strtolower()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.strtolower.php)

```
strtolower($_POST['username']);
```

complete code

```
if(empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true){
   $register_data = array(
    'username' => strtolower($_POST['username']),
    'first_name' => strtolower($_POST['first_name']),
    'last_name' => strtolower($_POST['last_name']),
    'email' => $_POST['email'],
    'password' => $_POST['password'],
    'joined' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'email_code' => md5($_POST['username'] + microtime()),
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you mean, change the case to lower. You can use:

php in built function i.e. strtolower function like this,

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$username = strtolower($username);
```

Answer (score 0):

try [strtolower()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.strtolower.php) to convert a string in lowercase

```
strtolower($_POST['username'])
```

**Also you need to escape your post strings to prevent sql injection**

Answer (score 0):

use strtolower()

```
$usernamestr = strtolower($username);
```

and insert this value in database